# How can I delete a model in django?

Tags: django, models

I'm installing a new app (social) on my django project.

When I enter `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` I get the following error

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x971d56c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
social.socialall: "client_name": CharFields require a "max_length" 
attribute that is a positive integer.
social.socialall: "customer_name": CharFields require a "max_length" attribute that is a positive integer.
social.socialall: "publisher_id": CharFields require a "max_length" attribute that is a positive integer.
social.socialall: "currency": CharFields require a "max_length" attribute that is a positive integer.
```

I created a social model a while back but never used it so deleted it from the code.

I'm trying to figure out where does `social.socialall` this lives. I'm assuming django.db.models but I'm querying my SQL database and can't find anything.

I only get this error message when I include social in installed_apps.

Comment: Your database doesn't matter at this point. The exception is raised because somewhere in your code you have this model class defined. Delete it and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is not in installed apps.

Afterwards all you have to do is unapply all migrations from this application.

So run this command

```
./manage.py migrate social zero
```

So this will undo all of the migrations made within application named **social**

Comment: This gives me the following  **app = models.get_app(app_label)
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/analytics_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 152, in get_app
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("App with label %s could not be found" % app_label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label social could not be found**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I created a models.py file. I then deleted the file but **models.pyc** remained in the folder. My IDE didn't display it, but it was there. Deleting the **.pyc** fixed it for me. Thanks Guys!